# "Variable ${workspaceFolder} can not be resolved" error in new VSC installation

Tags: python, r, visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Studio Code 1.87.2 followed by the addons for R and Python. I then opened an .ipynb notebook that a collaborator shared.

I tried running the first code section:

```
#load dataframe
xdata=read.csv("/Users/path/xdata.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",quote = "")
```

However, I get the errors below:

[image]

I'm not sure what these errors refer to though. I cannot find any ${workspaceFolder} variable in the code or in the settings.

An additional error that pops up if I reopen Visual Studio Code is:

[image]

..followed, if I click Yes there, by this:
[image]

I have very little experience with both R and Python, so this will be very basic / silly (apologies).

Comment: the error messages have a `^` character to read all of the text, do you have a workspace/folder open because the error says something like; `Please open a folder`

Comment: I only have the ipynb file open, no folders, but not sure if I understand your question. Sometimes another error message also appears though (have updated my question with it).

Comment: try create a folder, place ipynb file in folder, open folder in VSC and open ipynb file with VSC File Explorer

Comment: Thanks! I did this and the error went away, but now running the cells seems to do nothing. But it looks like this might be an interpreter/installation issue? https://ibb.co/ChvDNc5

Comment: Btw, I think this is the sort of error that takes many written exchanges to debug in writing on stackoverflow, but probably a few mins over a zoom screen sharing or smth. Is there such a thing (for free) ?